# Temporary tables

Tags: sql

I have two temp tables t1 and t2,
t1 containing:

```
Product    Sum(products)  StartDate
d1          10         06/03/2016
d2          20         13/03/2016 
d3          30         20/03/2016
```

based on the startdate

and t2 contaning:

```
subproducts   sum(subproduct) startdate
d1.a1           10            06/03/2016
d2.a2           20            13/03/2016
d3.a3           30            20/03/2016
```

t3 containing

```
product subproduct
d1        a1
d2        a2
d3        a3
```

```
create table t2 as(select t3.subproduct,t1.startdate,sum(subproduct) over(partition by t1.product) from t3,t1
where t3.product =t1.product
grouping by startdate
```

I need to first check if `sum(subproduct)` is zero, if not then calculate the `sum(product)/sum(subproduct)`, and then take the average of this value over 10 weeks assuming I have ten weeks data. Can this be done inside the temp table `t2` and how?

Comment: You need a way to join the two tables. From your data it looks like maybe the Product column of t1 maps to the first half the subproducts column of t2. Is this what you are intending?

Comment: please provide queries that you used to generate t1 and t2. I am assuming there's a product table, a subproduct table. what else?

Comment: I also have a table which contains the mapping between the product and the sub product where d1 is mapped to a1.This calculation needs to performed on the basis of the product

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? The `grouping` keyword is non-standard.